# How can i set the default values of controller parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I have a customers table on my database and a column named as "last_updated_by" . I want to add current users name as a plain text in this field.

I got devise installed on my app so it gives me the current_user parameter.I tried to add current_user.name to the customers_controllers permitted parameters but it did not worked.

```
1-
def customer_params
params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :last_updated_by=>current_user.name)
end

2-
def customer_params
  params[:last_updated_by] = current_user.name
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :last_updated_by)
end

3-
def customer_params
  last_updated_by = current_user.name
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :last_updated_by=>current_user.name)
end
```

How can i set some default values in controller.

Comment: You should explain more why you need a default value in your controller, because the best/easy way to set default value to a param with rails is on model

Comment: I explained it in the main post. I want to add last_updated_by information automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `last_updated_by` param to go within the customer_params (customer hash key for `ActionController::Parameters`), then:

```
before_action :set_last_updated_by_param, only: :create

private

def set_last_updated_by_param
  params[:customer][:last_updated_by] = params.dig(:customer, :name)
end
```

The before_action callback adds the new key `last_updated_by` on the `customer` params only before the create action is executed.

Notice, no need to modify the customer_params to permit it.

---

As showed by @JohanWentholt, `with_defaults` seems to be the best way. Go for it.

Waiting the OP chooses the correct answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't set a default value. If a value is already present in the params it is overwritten. Use the `||=` assignment operator instead.

Comment: Appreciated for answers but i am getting the error "undefined method `name' for :current_user:Symbol".

Comment: Okay i changed   params[:customer][:last_updated_by] = params.dig(:customer, :name) to   params[:customer][:last_updated_by] = current_user.name and it worked. But i am still curious why i can't define it in the permitted_params directly.

Comment: The answer still doesn't set a default this way. If you provide the `?customer[last_updated_by]=Some+Name` parameter it will be overwritten by the *set_last_updated_by_param* method.  The reason that no default is set when using permit is simply because the [*permit*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) method doesn't allow you to set defaults.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Default values for permitted params can be set via [.with_defaults](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-with_defaults)

Comment: `with_defaults` seems to be the best way. Go ahead for it.

Answer (score 15):

Since you're asking about setting a default value I suggest using the [`with_defaults`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-with_defaults) method, which is simply an (more expressive) alias for [`reverse_merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-reverse_merge).

```
def customer_params
  params
    .require(:customer)
    .permit(:name, :last_updated_by)
    .with_defaults(last_updated_by: current_user.name)
end
```

`reverse_merge` does the same thing as `merge`, the only difference is what happens for conflicting keys. `merge` uses the value of the hash passed through the parameters, whereas `reverse_merge` prefers the value of the receiver.

```
params = { a: 1, b: 2 }
defaults = { a: 4, c: 5 }
params.merge(defaults)         #=> { a: 4, b: 2, c: 5 }
params.reverse_merge(defaults) #=> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 5 }
#       ^ aka with_defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a default value only if `params[:last_updated_by]` is not present in the body of your request, you can try:

```
def create
  params[:last_updated_by] = params[:last_updated_by].blank? ? 'Default value' : params[:last_updated_by]
  Customer.new(params)
  # finish your controller method
end

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :last_updated_by)
end
```

Now if you need to set a default value on every create and update if `last_updated_by` is nil, you should do this on Customer model:

```
after_save :set_last_updated_by

def set_last_updated_by
  self.last_updated_by = self.last_updated_by.blank? ? 'Default value' : self.last_updated_by
end
```

Comment: `params[:last_updated_by] = params[:last_updated_by].blank? ? 'Default value' : params[:last_updated_by]` can be written as `params[:last_updated_by] ||=  'Default value' `  Nothing wrong with either version, just giving an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As method params.permit method is used to filter the parameter you want to create the object with, you can use any of the solution given above, but if you want to modify params in def customer_params then i would like to modify your 2nd solution

```
def customer_params
  params[:customer][:last_updated_by] = current_user.name 
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :last_updated_by)
end
```